# Spring AOP not working in maven multi module environment

Tags: java, maven, spring-aop

I have a java application build upon Spring 3.

My aspect `ConsumerAspect.java` is in separate maven module called `Aspect`. It has before advice and the pointcut like:

```
@Before("execution(* handle(..)) && args(inMessage,..)")
```

And the `handle()` method is in a different class called `EndpointListener.java` in a different maven module called Endpoint.

I am using load time weaving and my `aop.xml` looks like:

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose">
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.sabre.svm.ods.app.*"/>
        <include within="com.sabre.svm.producer.messaging.*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->        
        <aspect name="com.sabre.svm.ods.app.OdsConsumer"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

As stated above, the first include in the weaver element is the aspect and the second include in the weaver element points to the package which contains the `EndpointListener.java`.

My spring `applicationContext.xml` file contains

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>
<bean id="odsConsumerAspect" class="com.sabre.svm.ods.app.OdsConsumer">
</bean>
```

In the `pom.xml` of the `Aspect` module i have used the following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <argLine>
            -javaagent:C:/spring-agent-2.5.6.jar
        </argLine>
        <useSystemClassloader>true</useSystemClassloader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And lastly I have added the `Aspect` module as dependency in `Endpoint` module pom file.

Now when I execute the application, the `handle` method is not getting intercepted.

When I keep all the files in the same module it works.

I am not able to understand why it's not working. Can some one shed some light.